# Disable Microsoft Edge (Chromium) developer mode extensions pop up at startup

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, chromium

I switched to the fairly new Edge browser since it is chromium based and has better resource management and a better integration with Windows 10. Yet I am unable to get rid of the annoying pop up that got carried from Chrome. But at least, it was possible to get rid of the warning in Chrome by tweaking its 
extension policies; The trick doesn't work with Edge.

[image]

If someone managed to get rid of the pop up, please share how.

Comment: You mean none of these methods work - [disable developer mode extensions pop up in Chrome](//stackoverflow.com/q/23055651)? What about using the non-stable channel like Edge Beta or Canary?

Comment: Well, the question was asked like 5 years ago, I don't know if the answers are still relevant for Chrome let alone Edge; I came across it before, but since you mentioned it, I will try them one by one. As what concern Edge Insider Channels, Edge Canary, just like its Chrome equivalent, doesn't have the pop up; But there is no way I'll use it as my daily drive, too unstable.

Comment: Did you try to check by adding --disable-extensions-file-access-check argument to MS Edge shortcut file? If not, you can have a try and check the results.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, I just tried it; not working though but thanks.

Comment: It's like a security-related feature. I try to check the settings, options, registry, group policies but it looks like at present there is no way to disable this popup. I will try to discuss this issue with other engineers to know their opinion about it. If I get any useful information then I will try to provide you. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: If you open additional browser instances without closing first one, do the other instances show the popup? Kind of a dumb work around, but I noticed on Chrome that it suppresses the warning on all new opens while the initial one is still open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a patcher that works - https://github.com/Ceiridge/Chrome-Developer-Mode-Extension-Warning-Patcher

Answer (score 6):

Open the file `Preferences` located at

`C:\Users\Your_User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\`

search `{"allow_chrome_webstore":true,`

if not present, add `"dev_mode_warning_snooze_end_time":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",`

```
   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX = timestamp value
```

look like :
`{"allow_chrome_webstore":true,"dev_mode_warning_snooze_end_time":"99999999999000000","developer_mode":true}`

next pop up will appear  ~16/11/4769

*testing under Edge 96 Stable*

Comment: This workaround is patched up in the latest Edge dev build.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the [patcher](https://github.com/Ceiridge/Chrome-Developer-Mode-Extension-Warning-Patcher) is currently working.

As a side note the patcher has been updated 3 days ago and I did not have to tell it where to find the Edge installation folder or do any renaming of files, it worked great on auto install. New tabs, new windows, and new instances all come up with the warning disabled.

Comment: I can now confirm that Ceiridge's awesome patcher **still** works as of 4-Nov-2020. What a godsend!

Answer (score 2):

If you get Edge Dev or Canary instead of Edge Stable or Beta, the extension warning will go away. If you are already using Edge Stable copy  %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\ to %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge Dev\User Data\ and everything will transfer over.

Get Edge Dev or Canary from https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/ (DO NOT get Beta, as that has the extension warning)